# put magento "sort by" next to "show per page"

Tags: magento, layout

I'm trying to move the magento "sort by" drop-down option to be next to the "Show X per page" dropdown. Iv been somewhat successful.

Within the toolbar.phtml file (Template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml) I've taken the div with class "sort-by" and moved it and its contents to be within the "pager" div (same file(toolbar.phtml)), I have also modified the css to make it look right.

now if i visit any page within my site, the top toolbar has no functionality, but the bottom one is fine?!?!?

even though within the list.phtml they are called by the same line-->

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

anybody have even the slightest idea what could be causing this??

my toolbar code is below

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <div class="pager">
        <p class="amount">
            <?php if($this->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
                <?php echo $this->__('Items %s to %s of %s total', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <strong><?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?></strong>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>

            /****** This div was moved from below ******/
        <div class="sort-by">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
            <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                    <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_desc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_asc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="limiter">
            <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
            <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
            <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?php echo $_limit ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>



    </div>

    <?php if( $this->isExpanded() ): ?>
    <div class="sorter">
        <?php if( $this->isEnabledViewSwitcher() ): ?>
        <p class="view-mode">
            <?php $_modes = $this->getModes(); ?>
            <?php if($_modes && count($_modes)>1): ?>
            <label><?php echo $this->__('View as') ?>:</label>
            <?php foreach ($this->getModes() as $_code=>$_label): ?>
                <?php if($this->isModeActive($_code)): ?>
                    <strong title="<?php echo $_label ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($_code); ?>"><?php echo $_label ?></strong>&nbsp;
                <?php else: ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getModeUrl($_code) ?>" title="<?php echo $_label ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($_code); ?>"><?php echo $_label ?></a>&nbsp;
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    /****** Div moved from here ******/

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the corresponding css as well?

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, iv got a feeling iv got a hidden div over the top making it unreachable by the mouse, i only thought of this problem 2 mins before leaving work, once i have tried moving this box and if i still get problems i will post the css. but really all the css does is float the "sort-by" to the right so I cant see that being the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as you said there could be div overlaying. so, your top toolbar is under transparent div which blocks the mouse click triggers. Link to the page would help to find the issue faster.